# How do I resume a tar command which was killed

Tags: tar

I was doing a : `tar -cvf` and I had to killed it with `ctrl-C`.
I know I should have done a `Ctrl-Z` and then bring back the task to foreground... but it's not the story.

Can I resume from the point I stopped the task ?

Comment: Is there an incomplete tar file in the destination location?

Comment: Yes there is an incomplete tar.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This method will recreate your tar archive, and append the finished part to the existing file. This can be useful if backing up over a network connection. You will likely result in a corrupt archive if any of the data in your INFILES has changed. Be sure to test your archive after completion.

Change INFILES and OUTFILE to the correct names on the following line.

```
INFILES="my folder"; OUTFILE="archive.tgz"; SIZE="$(wc -c < $OUTFILE)"; tar -cz --to-stdout "$INFILES" | tail -c +$(($SIZE+1)) >> "$OUTFILE"
```

Explanation:

`SIZE="$(wc -c < $OUTFILE)"` # Get the current size of the archive.

`tar -cz --to-stdout "$INFILES" |` # Begin creating archive and send output to `tail` command.

`tail -c +$(($SIZE+1)) >>` # Disregard the data before $SIZE+1, and resume the rest of the archive $OUTFILE.

Comment: I assume this is faster than just restarting the tar process because its not actually writing anything to disk?

Comment: This seems like a really bad idea; If anything in `INFILES` has changed, or tar just happens to dump the files in a different order, it will make a corrupted tar file with files potentially missing and/or duplicated, and there will be no error. Please do not do this. See the other answer: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/560042/38485

Answer (score 9):

What I do in the case, that I have an incomplete `tar` archive, I create a list of the files in the archive:

```
tar tf archive.tar | sed -e '/\/$/d' -e x -e '/^$/d' >files-done
```

The `sed` command deletes all those lines, that have a trailing slash: These are directories, not files, and we want to dump the directories again and only skip those files in those directories, that we have already in the first tar archive. Furthermore, we let `sed` delete the last filename, because that has very likely been dumped only partially, so we will archive it again.

Then just pass the `files-done` list via the -X option to a new `tar` command:

```
tar cfvX archive2.tar files-done SOURCEDIR
```

Make sure to use a different output filename on the new tar command, or you will overwrite your partial archive. Do not try to directly append to the corrupt tar archive.

Comment: `tar -tf` will list incomplete files, so you should also remove the last file from the list I believe.

Comment: @Shelvacu Yes, the last file needs to be deleted. That's what the `-e x -e '/^$/'` construct in my code is for. And that's why I wrote: "Furthermore, we let `sed` delete the last filename, because that has very likely been dumped only partially, so we will archive it again."

Comment: Is this applied to tar.gz too?

Comment: It similarly works for compressed tar archives. Just make sure to use the correct decompression options in the `tar tf` part of my example command.

Comment: Instead of `tar cfvX ...` you could instead use `tar rfvX ...` to append the remaining files to the existing tar file.

Comment: @fourpastmidnight The original question asked about a case, where writing the original tar archive had to be interrupted. I strongly advise against trying to add to the end of such an archive!

Comment: Good point, I forgot, you're not, for example, replacing the last file in the archive (which may be a partial, the command I provided would only _append_, and could cause corruption. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The best solution would be to delete the tar file and restart the process prepended with `nohup` and appended with `&`. Alternatively, you could run `tar -tfv` and use that as an exclude for the new `tar -cvf`.

Comment: `tar -cvf` will overwrite the existing file. Did you mean `tar -rvf`? Also, the last file that was written to the archive was likely incomplete.

Comment: So the idea is to make a list of the files which are already in the tarball, minus the last one which is probably incomplete. And then run a `tar -rvf` ?

Answer (score 2):

You can't; you just need to start over.